# Chart won't render upon state change

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am testing out react-native and I am trying to make a simple lineChart which redraws on props change. I have a parent component HomeScreen which passes an array of integers as props to the LineChart child component. However, the LineChart is never drawn.

I have tried passing in an already initialized array with dummy values. The lineChart child component will then render, but it won't re-render on subsequent state changes.

I have checked the actual values of state and props in react-devtools, and the childcomponent does receive the props and the state is updated. How can I make the chart render the props I pass it?

UPDATE: So I took the advice from the replies here, and made the component functional. The chart now renders, but there is still something wrong with the prop type. I'll investigate further and read up on the react-native-svg documentation. Thanks!

```
    enter code here
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'

const BeatChart = ({ data }) => (
      <LineChart
        style={{ height: 200 }}
        data={data}
        svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(0, 255, 255)' }}
        contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
      >
        <Grid />
      </LineChart>
); 


export default BeatChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need state in this example, so you could just use the functional component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'

const BeatChart = ({ data }) => (
  <LineChart
    style={{ height: 200 }}
    data={data}
    svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(0, 255, 255)' }}
    contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
  >
    <Grid />
  </LineChart>
);


export default BeatChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

since the render occurs on every change in props, you can comment this part of the code.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.data !== prevState.data) {
      return { data: nextProps.data };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

even if you want to implement it, use *componentWillmount* if needed.

otherwise the code works fine.

so your final code be like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'

class BeatChart extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data: [],//your data
    }

  };

  // static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  //   if (nextProps.data != prevState.data) {
  //     return { this.setState({data: nextProps.data}) };
  //   }
  //   return null;
  // }



  render() {

    const arr = this.state.data;


    return (
      <LineChart
        style={{ height: 200 }}
        data={arr}
        svg={{ stroke: 'rgb(0, 255, 255)' }}
        contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
      >
        <Grid />
      </LineChart>
    )
  }

}

export default BeatChart;
```